# R using optim and foreach generates error of ancestor must be an environment

Tags: r, doparallel

I am running a script in R where I am doing some optimization. My code does following things: loop over some locations and in each location, create a cluster using `foreach` and `doParallel` and run the `optim` function. I get some strange error that says :

> Error in { : task 24 failed - "`ancestor` must be an environment"

I can't find why this error occurs and wondered if anyone can tell me the cause of it.

Comment: Can you post sample code and data? The problem as posted is not reproducible.

Comment: okay. let me try to post something since it is a big script.